# Unity type registration for generic factory method

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container

I'm trying to get familiar with asp.net mvc and currently I'm working on setting up logging.

I've had a look at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and read about how to set it up but I'm struggling with the type registration in unity.

I'd like to setup the type for

```
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
```

I can do so with

```
    private static void RegisterLoggingTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddConsole()
            .AddDebug();
        container.RegisterType<ILogger<HomeController>>(new InjectionFactory(c => loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HomeController>()));
    }
```

But I don't want to have to declare one for every type. I tried

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ILogger<>), new InjectionFactory((c,t,s) => loggerFactory.CreateLogger(t)));
```

But this is returning an `ILogger` instead of an `ILogger(of HomeController)`

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: I see that you already found yourself an answer. But you should be able to do this with buildtracking instead. This example is for Log4Net, but the theory is mostly the same. http://blog.baltrinic.com/software-development/dotnet/log4net-integration-with-unity-ioc-container

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've figured this out. I needed to use reflection to generate the generic method then to invoke that.

```
        var factoryMethod = typeof(LoggerFactoryExtensions).
                            GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public).
                            First(x => x.ContainsGenericParameters);

        container.RegisterType(typeof(ILogger<>), new InjectionFactory((c, t, s) =>
        {
            var genFactoryMethod = factoryMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
            return genFactoryMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { loggerFactory });
        }));
```